# How to get time with respect to another timezone in android

Tags: java, android, timezone, jodatime

I want to create an alarm application for FIFA 2014 world cup matches in which i have a server which stores the date and time for the matches in Brazil/Acre and my client is an android application and an android device may have any of the possible timezone so the my problem is i want to convert the Brazil/Acre timing to the local android device timing with different timezone and after lot of googled i came to know about joda data and time lib but it is too slow in android so please suggest any code that will work for me.

Comment: What format are your dates in (strings, milliseconds etc etc?)

Comment: year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth, hourOfDay, minuteOfHour, secondOfMinute

Comment: So as a String? Edit your question to show an example.

Comment: String sdate=""+cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-"+cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"-"+cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+" "+cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+":"+cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);

Comment: I mean an example of one of the date strings. Also...edit your question instead of posting code in a comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54845/discussion-between-neeraj-sharma-and-squonk).

Comment: why dont you save server time in in UTC time and covert those time according to device time .

Comment: i have to convert at the device's local time zone and server has the Brazil/Acre time saved and i cant change that timing i am not authorized for that

Comment: have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108356/get-time-of-different-time-zones-on-selection-of-time-from-time-picker and this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429357/date-and-time-conversion-to-some-other-timezone-in-java

Comment: if u get `TimeStamp` from server then it will be easy to convert that in `Current DateTime` format

Comment: http://singztechmusings.wordpress.com/2011/06/23/java-timezone-correctionconversion-with-daylight-savings-time-settings/

Comment: try out :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238661/how-to-convert-date-time-from-one-time-zone-to-another-time-zone

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my opinion [Time class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html) is the best for your job. Also it is **Android API** not general Java API.

Here I mentioned some of useful methods for your job:

```
void switchTimezone(String timezone)
```

> Convert this time object so the time represented remains the same, but is instead located in a different timezone.

```
static String getCurrentTimezone()
```

> Returns the timezone string that is currently set for the device.

And if you want to save a time in a timezone independed manner, you can convert to milliseconds (in UTC) by `toMillis()` method and then retrieve it by `set(long millis)` method.

If something is unclear please tell me!

**UPDATE**

Example:

```
long timeMillis = /* get time milliseconds form the server */
Time time = new Time();
time.set(timeMillis);

/* changing time zone */
time.switchTimezone(/* your desired timezone in string format */);

/* getting time as string  */
String timeString = time.format("%Y%m%dT%H%M%S"); // you can change format as you wish
```

[Here is a table](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/) for formatting times

Answer (score 2):

You could use this code, which substracts the hour-difference between Brazil and the local timezone. Just replace `yourDate` with a Date-object.

```
//code...
yourDate.setTime(yourDate.getTime() - getDifferenceInMillis());
//code...

public int getDifferenceInMillis() {
    // Local Time
    int localMinute = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int localHour = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int localDay = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Brazil Time
    Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Brazil/Acre"));
    c.setTimeInMillis(new Date().getTime());
    int brazilMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int brazilHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int brazilDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Difference between Brazil and local
    int minuteDifference = brazilMinute - localMinute;
    int hourDifference = brazilHour - localHour;
    int dayDifference = brazilDay - localDay;
    if (dayDifference != 0) {
        hourDifference = hourDifference + 24;
    }
    return (hourDifference * 60 + minuteDifference) * 60 * 1000;
}
```

Comment: what about the minute difference??

Comment: It now also calculates the minute-difference. Second-difference is not needed, since timezones only differ in minutes.

Comment: but your code always give the same result -9 difference my local time zone is GMT+05:30

Comment: I changed the code, you need to copy it again ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should store your date has a long or timestamp in your server. If you don't want you can anyway send your date as a long generate from your database date. Then create your calendar instance like that :

```
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(new Date(yourdatelong));
```

You can have to multiplie and add some constant in your long. In java the definition is "the number of milisecond since 1970 1/1 00:00:00". It is differents in C#, for exemple ( number of nanoseconde from 1/1/1900, if I remenber well).

Like that you are sure to set the same date in all your device. When it is done, you just have to put the timezone that you want in your calendar to display the local time.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

You can have many option to manage time and display it in this class.

Comment: this is not i am looking for

Comment: Damned, so i don't understand what you want to do... You want to change the display of your date or you want to change your date ?

Comment: Read the question again carefully. I mentioned that i want to change server timing that is in Brazil/Acre to local timing with date.

Comment: I edit my answer tell me if it is better

Answer (score 0):

If dates are stored in server time zone (Brazil/Acre), you should load date time from DB, convert it to UTC time zone and send to client. On client side change UTC to local time zone:

**Server side:**

```
DateTime dateOnServer = // load date from db
DateTime dateUTC = dateOnServer.withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC); // convert to UTC  
String dateAsStringUTC = dateUTC.toString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
// send 'dateAsStringUTC' to client
```

**Client side:**

```
String dateAsStringUTC = // receive date from server
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"); // parser for date 
DateTime dateOnClient= dtf.parseDateTime(dateAsStringUTC); 
// 'dateOnClient' will be in client time zone 'DateTimeZone.getDefault()'
```

Answer (score -2):

I faced same problem like you...

I got the solution using `SimpleDateFormat`

```
SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
sourceFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date parsed = format.parse("2011-03-01 15:10:37"); // => Date is in UTC now

TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago");
SimpleDateFormat destFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
destFormat.setTimeZone(tz);

String result = destFormat.format(parsed);
```

this may help you..

Comment: for more detail you can refer this link [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) 

it will give you detain information about your problem

Comment: All that does is format a date in a different way. It doesn't convert a UTC time to a local time based on timezone and daylight savings variations.

Comment: **"there is my code"** : No, that's not your code. You've copied and pasted it from another answer here on SO and you haven't attributed the original answer.

Comment: first time when i gave answer it was my code...but when i edited the answer i forgot to remove that line...brother.

Comment: dont worry prag it happens but keep answering i will vote you up when your are right