# Unique timezone for each reminder

Tags: android

What i want to know is, is there any app in android which allows me to set a time of different time zone for a reminder. For example i need to get an alert at 2:00pm London time in my phone without changing my phone's time zone.

Comment: an app?? so it is not about code?

Comment: nope, i don't know who to ask so i asked here sorry for disappointing you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23993692/3492139. This might help you for code